# When is a smooth function locally equivalent to a truncation of its Taylor series?

Tags: singularity-theory

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and let $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth proper function.  For $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ let

$$T_p(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_n=0}^{\infty} c_{i_1,\ldots,i_n} (x_1-p_1)^{i_1} \cdots (x_n-p_n)^{i_n}$$

be its Taylor series around $p$ (considered as a formal power series; I am not making any assumptions about its convergence).  For $k \geq 0$, define $T_{p,k}$ to be the truncation of $T_p$ to terms of degree at most $k$, so $T_{p,k}$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$.

Question: What assumptions can I put on $f$ to ensure that the following holds:

For all $p \in U$, there exists

1. Some $k \geq 0$,
2. Some neighborhood $V$ of $p$,
3. Some neighborhood $W$ of $f(p) \in \mathbb{R}$ containing $f(V)$,
4. Homeomorphisms $\phi_1:V \rightarrow V$ and $\phi_2:W \rightarrow W$

such that $f|_V = \phi_2 \circ T_{k,p}|_{V} \circ \phi_1$.

By the basic results of Morse theory, this will be true if all the singularities of $f$ in $U$ are non degenerate.  But it should be true in *far* greater generality.

ps: Feel free to re-tag, I wasn't sure what tags were appropriate.

Comment: I would say that this is true for any isolated singularity (they are determined by finite jets). I think this should be written in Arnold, Varchenko, Gussein-Zade's book.

Comment: In the above book of Aenold, Varchenko Gussein_Zade  this result is referred to as Tougeron's  theorem It states  that a function $f$is equivalent to its jet at a point $p$, if the quotient of the ring of germs of smooth functions at $p$  modulo the Jacobian ideal of $f$ (the generated by the jets of the first order derivatives $\partial_{x_i} f$ at the point $p$) is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra